# Detect new-line character for auto enter new line text on UITextView on iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, newline

When typing on UITextView on iOS app, if text is beyond the width of UITextView, UITextView will automatically enter new line and continue typing, but the problem is when get the text out, it's still just one-line text.

[image: The 'M' character is automatically broken into new line after 'O' character]

But when I get the text from this textview

```
NSString* newtext = textview.text;
```

The value of newtext will be "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOMMM" (all is one-line) but I'm expected it will be "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO\nMMM" (notice the '\n' character notify the new line)

Is there any way to do that

Comment: It doesn't automatically enter a newline, it just wraps around... You're saying you want a string representation of textview.text to be able to reflect the newline?

Comment: @LyndseyScott, yes, it's my desire

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UITextView` doesn't automatically enter a newline character once its text reaches the end of the line -- it simply wraps around with a line break. But if you want a string representation of the `UITextView` text which includes newline characters to indicate the various line breaks, try this:

```
// This method takes in the `UITextView` and returns the string
// representation which includes the newline characters
- (NSString*)textViewWithNewLines:(UITextView*)textView {

    // Create a variable to store the new string
    NSString *stringWithNewlines = @"";

    // Get the height of line one and store it in
    // a variable representing the height of the current
    // line
    int currentLineHeight = textView.font.lineHeight;

    // Go through the text view character by character
    for (int i = 0 ; i < textView.text.length ; i ++) {

        // Place the cursor at the current character
        textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(i, 0);

        // And use the cursor position to help calculate
        // the current line height within the text view
        CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;

        // If the y value of the cursor is greater than
        // the currentLineHeight, we've moved onto the next line
        if (cursorPosition.y > currentLineHeight) {

            // Increment the currentLineHeight such that it's
            // set to the height of the next line
            currentLineHeight += textView.font.lineHeight;

            // If there isn't a user inputted newline already,
            // add a newline character to reflect the new line.
            if (textView.text.length > i - 1 &&
                [textView.text characterAtIndex:i-1] != '\n') {
                stringWithNewlines = [stringWithNewlines stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
            }

            // Then add the character to the stringWithNewlines variable
            stringWithNewlines = [stringWithNewlines stringByAppendingString:[textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
        } else {

            // If the character is still on the "current line" simply
            // add the character to the stringWithNewlines variable
            stringWithNewlines = [stringWithNewlines stringByAppendingString:[textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
        }
    }

    // Return the string representation of the text view
    // now containing the newlines
    return stringWithNewlines;
}
```

Comment: Thank @LyndseyScott, it works like a charm. But I want to know that what actually is the cursorPosition, is it the cursor when we type text?

Comment: @pf2707 Yes, it's a variable indicating the cursor position as set in the previous line with textView.selectedRange. I'm using the cursor position as a moving "cheat" of sorts to help find the position of each character.

Comment: I got it, sometimes we need some cheats to complete the goal, thanks for your great idea, it really save me

Comment: @LyndseyScott would you know a similar method to apply to Strings? Or should I just use a Text View instead? Thanks.